# Case sensitive string replacement in Eclipse or Notepad++

Tags: regex, eclipse, notepad++, replace

I am using Eclipse and Notepad ++ to perform replacement multiple files (xml & java)

I am trying to replace [Pp]roduct[Mm]ember with [Ff]und[Mm]ember in one single replacement and preserving the case.

```
ProductMember -> FundMember
productMember -> fundMember
productmember -> fundmember
```

Using capturing groups it is easy to keep the case of the M from Member, but I am clueless for the P replacement.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to do that with regex. Why do you need to accomplish that in one search&replace?

Comment: The search and replace must be performed in 10 folders. Doing it in a single replacement is reducing the risk of errors since I would require 10 search and replace instead of 20.

Comment: @leconcombreless In such case I recommend to use scripts. Or refactoring in IDE if possible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In eclipse you can use the regex retain-case operator: \C. To solve your example you should search for "Product", replace with "\CFund" (be sure to tick the Regular expression option). This will replace Product with Fund and product with fund.

Update:

Make sure not to have the Case Sensitive box checked.

Comment: If this works there must be cases where it doesn't. I just tried it on a CamelCasedWord I wanted to replace with AnotherCamelCasedWord and despite the \C it always performed a direct replace without switching case where it should.

Comment: I couldn't get this working until I realised that I had the 'Case-sensitive' box checked, after unchecking it the replacement worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

np++ regex is very poor, you can use a perl one-liner to do the job:

```
perl -pi.back -e's{(productmember)}{ uc fundmember | (uc $1 ^ $1) . (uc(substr $1, -1) ^ substr $1, -1) x (length($new) - length $1) }egi;' theFile
```

Extracted from [perl faq6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS?)

Answer (score 0):

*Although* Notepad++ lacks the `\C` feature available in Eclipse, some case-sensitive replacement use cases can still be solved with Notepad++, although it is not as general as the `\C` feature. (Technically I believe NPP uses `\C` as a synonym for `.`).

### Feature Reference

Referring you to the Notepad++ user manual, there's a section called [Substition Escape Sequences](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#substitution-escape-sequences) which describes supported *substitution* escape sequences such as:

- `\L` (make following characters in the substitution expression lowercase until `\E` is seen)
- `\U` (make following characters in the substitution expression uppercase until `\E` is seen).

Following that, there's a section called [Substitition Conditionals](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#substitution-conditionals) which describes features allowing you to do a substitution only if a specific capturing group matched.

### Example

Suppose I have the string `foo FOO foo FOO` and I want to perform a case-sensitive substitution `s/foo/bar` so my result is `bar BAR bar BAR`. With the above-mentioned Notepad++ features I can do this substitution.

#### Match regular expression

```
(foo)|(FOO)
```

#### Substitution regular expression

```
(?1\L:\U)bar
```

The above subtitution expression will replace the match with `\Lbar` (obviously the same as literal `bar`) if `foo` was matched and `\Ubar` (equivalent to literal `BAR`) if `FOO` matched. I omitted the `\E` because it isn't needed since the end-of-expression does the trick.

For correct results, don't forget to turn on the case sensitivity checkbox!